# Identify different hosts which are the same environment login by ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, difference

I ssh another host, i know i can ifconfig to realize not the localhost. I want a simple and clear way.  Such as change the color of PS1 or something else.              It's the remote server.
[image]

and now it's my local server.
[image]

Is there anyideas?

Answer (score 0):

Theoritically you can make two pcs exactly same in environment. They can have same hostname, OS, applications etc. So the only way to differentiate two PCs on a network is by IP address.

To assign IP address, DHCP protocol uses MAC address which as supposed to be globally unique. So to be completely sure, you have to check IP address or MAC address to differentiate between PCs.

But practically, checking hostname will also work.

```
~$ hostname
ubuntu-laptop
```

Comment: Yeah, many commands can show the difference. We always execute many commands,but there is no difference when i input them, so i always check which server it is. So, i want to change color or similar strategy that i can clearly identify them.

Comment: I think the problem is that we can't modify the ssh 's input and output, so we can not to add a decorator to the output.